# Regular expression: Get the matched value of each match in a Kleene-star expression?

Tags: javascript, regex

In particular, is this possible with Javascript?

```
>> "Version 1.2.3.4".match(/\S+ (\d+)(\.\d+)*/)
["Version 1.2.3.4", "1", ".4"]
```

It's obvious $2 gets set to the last Kleene-"match". Is there no built-in method to retrieve the rest (`".2"`, `".3"`)?

If this cannot be done easily in JS, could Perl do it?

UPDATE: Many of the answers so far have been "workarounds" which work because of the simplicity of my example. If the part that repeated that I wanted to match was more than just a number, they wouldn't work.

However, a very valid solution does exist: use `/expr/g` global regex matching: just filter out the parts that repeat and use that. I find this to be somewhat less flexible than the more generally applicable `*` operator but it will obviously get the job done in most cases.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Regex in JavaScript, like most other regex flavors, only captures the last value of the capturing group if it is matched repeatedly. The only well known regex lib (that I know of) where you get access to all of the previous matched captures is the one in .NET.

So no, you can't do this in JS.

In Perl there are a couple of ways you can accomplish such things. One of the more elegant is probably to use `\G` (which works in PCRE too).

For example:

```
"Version 1.2.3.4" =~ /(?:\S+ |\G(?!^)\.)(\d+)/g
```

Returns (in list context):

```
(1, 2, 3, 4)
```

Comment: Can you please explain in details that Perl tricky regex? It works fine, just hard to read. Thanks.

Comment: `\G` is the key, it matches the position where the previous match ended (or beginning of string if first match, which is why we use `(?!^)` to avoid that match). So the expression would match `\S+ (\d+)`, and then repeat matching `\.(\d+)` at the end of the previous match.

Comment: I know `\G`, but don't understand that tricky `(?!^)`. It is negative lookahead that do not allow beginning? Is that possible? So that will just skip first match?

Comment: `(?!foo)` is a negative lookahead, it fails if the following matches `foo`. `^` matches the beginning of string. Put that together, and you get `(?!^)` which fails only if current position is beginning of string. As said it is used so that `\G` does not match at the beginning of string. Without using that a string as `.1.2.3` would match just fine.

Comment: Ooooh - I see what you mean, you prevent that regex to match inputs that would start with dot, correct?

Answer (score 1):

Why not match the whole version string, then split by `.`?

```
>> "Version 1.2.3.4".match(/\S+ (\d+(?:\.\d+)*)/)[1].split('.')
```

Answer (score 0):

Regex `\.?\d+` will return you what you need, but you have to run this regex for all matches, not just one...

```
var n=str.match(/\.?\d+/g);
```

If you want to match just numbers without leading dot, then go with regex `\d+`.

```
var n=str.match(/\d+/g);
```

Answer (score 0):

Just capture the whole version number string and then split on the period character.

Regex for matching the whole number: `/((?:\d+)(?:\.\d+)*)/`

Then simply call `split` on the resulting capture.

Comment: Note that this will not retain the periods (if those are important).